# springBoot and hibernate 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I train with springboot and a mariadb database. When I test for data recovery, I get this message in postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-03-03T13:53:18.609+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/user/all"
}
```

. I tried several tutorials in copy paste and I always have the same message. I will also put the message that is in the console. Thank you in advance for your help.

controller

```
package controller;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import service.UsersService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UsersController {


    private UsersService usersService;

    public UsersController(UsersService usersService) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> getUsers() {
        List<Users> users = usersService.getUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service

```
package service;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import repository.UsersRepository;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UsersService {

    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UsersService(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public List<Users> saveUsers(List<Users>users){
        return usersRepository.saveAll(users);
    }

    public Users saveUsers(Users users){
       return usersRepository.save(users);
    }

    public List<Users> getUsers(){
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Users getUserById(int id_user){
        return usersRepository.findById(id_user).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Respository

```
package repository;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

}
```

Model

```
package model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_user;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="adress")
    private String adress;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

}
```

Application properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Console

```
2022-03-03 14:52:57.479  INFO 24188 --- [           main] c.p.database.databaseApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-03 14:52:58.412  INFO 24188 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-03 14:52:58.435  INFO 24188 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-03 14:52:59.190  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-03 14:52:59.204  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-03 14:52:59.204  INFO 24188 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-03-03 14:52:59.370  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-03 14:52:59.370  INFO 24188 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1816 ms
2022-03-03 14:52:59.627  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-03-03 14:52:59.696  INFO 24188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-03-03 14:52:59.892  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-03 14:53:00.046  INFO 24188 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-03 14:53:00.252  INFO 24188 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-03 14:53:00.272  INFO 24188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2022-03-03 14:53:00.652  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-03 14:53:00.666  INFO 24188 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-03 14:53:00.722  WARN 24188 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-03-03 14:53:01.296  INFO 24188 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-03 14:53:01.317  INFO 24188 --- [           main] c.p.database.databaseApplication   : Started dataBaseApplication in 4.589 seconds (JVM running for 5.786)
2022-03-03 14:53:18.493  INFO 24188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-03 14:53:18.493  INFO 24188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-03 14:53:18.495  INFO 24188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Comment: Are you using spring boot's default web mvc configuration, or do you have a file with custom config?

Comment: @IsmaelSarmento Sarmento I used spring initializ to create my project. So I think it's the default

Comment: I provided an answer if it satisfy your requirement please accept it as answer to improve the community otherwise feel free to comment !

Answer (score 1):

Every thing on the controller class is implemented properly and there is definitely no need for other layers implementation to share, you probably use **SpringBootServletInitializer**, in the main class add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and override **SpringApplicationBuilder** method as

```html
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Otherwise if you use **SpringApplication** to sun the project make sure the main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and be some thing like

```html
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

And final thing check the presence of spring boot starter [web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) dependency in you pom file

```html
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

If you do not use spring boot parent do not forget to add the proper version to web starter artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fou , I'm using SpringApplication. I have the parent that is present and the spring-boot-starter-web dependency. But it doesn't work. ``` <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent> ```

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency> `

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>`